# Xcode iPhone simulator is not launching app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cordova

I am creating an app in IOS platform with Cordova (2.1.0) framework. When I select the iPhone simulator (6.1) with Xcode 4.5.2 and give a run, the build succeeds but the app is not launching on the simulator. Why is this happening?

Comment: Once quit your xcode and reset and restart your simulator. Check once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reset your simulator and quit your xcode and Simulator. Then Restart the xcode again. Clean the Code and now run the project. It should work properly. Hope it helps you.